# обновить вложенный PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android

Файл настроек содержит в себе вложенный `PreferenceScreen`, в который входят две категории по 2 параметра из внешней библиотеки [Android Color Picker](https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna) и вызов диалога, в котором я удаляю значения настроек, для возрата к настройкам по умолчанию. Вопрос такой - как обновить внутренний `PreferenceScreen` для показа изменения настроек? После закрытия диалога настроек, цвет не меняется на дефолтным.

код настроек:

```
    <PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="key_pref_preference_screen">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_category_db"> 
        <qqq.qqq.settings.MyPreferenceDialog
            android:key="pref_key_clear_learn"
            android:summary="@string/pref_description_clear_learn"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_clear_learn">

        </qqq.qqq.settings.MyPreferenceDialog>
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_category_rest">            
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:key="pref_key_check_animation"
            android:summary="@string/pref_check_animation_summary"
            android:title="@string/pref_check_animation_title" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="key_pref_custom_inter"
        android:summary="@string/pref_custom_inter_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_custom_inter">
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_custom_inter_buttons">

            <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
                android:defaultValue="@color/color_inter_color_font_button"
                android:key="key_pref_custom_inter_color_font_button"
                android:summary="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_font_button_summary"
                android:title="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_font_button_title" />

            <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
                android:defaultValue="@color/color_inter_color_background_button"
                android:key="key_pref_custom_inter_color_background_button"
                android:summary="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_background_button_summary"
                android:title="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_background_button_title" />

        </PreferenceCategory>

        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_custom_inter_show">
            <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
                android:defaultValue="@color/color_inter_color_font"
                android:key="key_pref_custom_inter_color_font"
                android:summary="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_font_summary"
                android:title="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_font_title" />

            <yuku.ambilwarna.widget.AmbilWarnaPreference
                android:defaultValue="@color/color_inter_color_background"
                android:key="key_pref_custom_inter_color_background"
                android:summary="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_background_summary"
                android:title="@string/pref_custom_inter_color_background_title" />

        </PreferenceCategory>

        <qqq.qqq.settings.MyPreferenceDialog
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:key="pref_key_clear_custom_inter"
            android:summary="@string/pref_clear_custom_inter_summary"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_clear_custom_inter">

        </qqq.qqq.settings.MyPreferenceDialog>
    </PreferenceScreen>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вам надо пересоздать активити настроек после изменения значений в настройках?..

Comment: да, я находил пример, как это реализовать, но это не работало именно на вложенный PreferenceScreen

Comment: Всё ещё не очень понимаю. Вы пробовали `recreate()` вызвать и это не помогло?

Comment: `setPreferenceScreen(null);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` вот это пробовал, если вложенного PreferenceScreen нет, то работает и меня устраивает результат, но с вложенным не работает

Comment: Ну... У вас какой-то странный подход... Попробуйте активити пересоздать...

Comment: Подправил ответ